JSON to Pandas Dataframe with null values and missing columns
I am working with a JSON file that is designed as such:
f = {'results':
              [{'tables':
                        [{'rows': [{'column1': 'dog', 'column2': 'blue', 'column3': 'sad'},
                                  { 'column2': 'red', 'column3': 'happy'},
                                  {'column1': 'bird', 'column2': 'green'}]
      }]}]} 

DESIRED pandas dataframe that accounts for rows with missing columns:
      column1     column2     column3
        dog         blue        sad
                    red        happy
        bird        green        

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Just grab the rows like so pd.DataFrame(f['results'][0]['tables'][0]['rows'])

Once you've read your data, you can normalise it as a normal dictionary, see below should do it:
import pandas as pd

# read the file
data = pd.read_json('my_dummy_file.json')

# normalise your data
rows = data['results'][0]['tables'][0]['rows']
df = pd.json_normalize(rows)

# fill missing values
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

print(df)

  column1 column2 column3
0     dog    blue     sad
1             red   happy
2    bird   green

